# Searching a DataTable built by SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, active-directory

I am trying to do a `SELECT *` from a SQL Server table where user information is stored, then compare those entries to an Active Directory database.

It works if I specify a particular person, but it errors when I try to blanket search and put the results into a datatable. `Code` and `Description` are one in the same.

In the database, the code is what is in the description field of AD. So what should happen is it pulls all the data from the database into a `DataTable`, for each result in the `DataTable` I search AD and return the email address in the email field of AD. Again, it works when I put in a specific first name and last name, but I just get an unhandled exception error when I use the below code.

Here is the code. Thank you!

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string APIdbUser = "dbuser";
        string APIdbServer = "dbserver";
        string APIdbUserPW = "dbpassword";
        string APIdbDatabase = "thedatabase";
        string TrustedConnection = "no";
        var ConnectionTimeout = "30";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + APIdbUser + ";" +
                                   "password=" + APIdbUserPW + ";server=" + APIdbServer + ";" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=" + TrustedConnection + ";" +
                                   "database=" + APIdbDatabase + "; " +
                                   "connection timeout=" + ConnectionTimeout))
        {
            using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE FirstName!='NULL' AND LastName!='NULL' AND Gender!='NULL';", myConnection))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string ldapAddress = "LDAP://url";
            string ldapusername = "ldapuser";
            string ldappassword = "ldapuser";

            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapAddress, ldapusername, ldappassword);
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

            ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)))(givenName=" + dr.Field<string>("FirstName") + ")(sn=" + dr.Field<string>("LastName") + ")(description=" + dr.Field<string>("Code") + "))";
            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

            if (dr.Field<string>("Code") == rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This users email address is: " + rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString());
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(dr.Field<string>("FirstName") + " " + dr.Field<string>("LastName"));
        }
}
```

Here is how I fixed it

```
if (rs != null)
{
    if (dr.Field<string>("Code") == rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value.ToString())
    {
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This email is N/A.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This users email address is: " + rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WHERE FirstName!='NULL' AND LastName!='NULL' AND Gender!='NULL'` - why are you literally storing the text `'NULL'` in your table as opposed to leaving the field `NULL`?

Comment: What error you are getting? On which line of code?

Comment: "NullReferenceUnhandled" An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ProjectName.  @Siyual I actually would rather have it be SELECT * FROM dbo.users and leave it at that. It really doesn't matter, I just get an error.

Error occurs at the IF statement.

Comment: There are plenty of objects in condition of `if`.  `rs` could be null, GetDirectoryEntry method might be returning null, Properties array could be null, the Value of the property could be null. You need to check which is causing the issue and handle in the code properly.

Comment: So in this situation, is there a way I can tell it to ignore entries with null values? I have tried adding opperands to ignore these like && rs != null ect ect, there are over 9000 users in AD and if any of those users have a null field I cannot sift through those haha

Comment: Interesting find. There are apparently users that do not exist in Active Directory, but do in the database I am checking. If the search doesn't return a response, you'd think it would just skip over it. I think that's where it is getting hung up. Looking into a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had to check IF NOT null

```
 if (rs != null)
            {
                if (dr.Field<string>("Code") == rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value.ToString())
                {
                    if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This email is N/A.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This users email address is: " + rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```